# Question about test function

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm reading this [book](https://www.amazon.com.br/Essentials-Statistical-Inference-G-Young/dp/0521548667/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=essentials%20statistical%20inference&qid=1608609457&s=books&sr=1-1) and on page 66, the author gives this example about hypothesis testing:

[image]

I don't understand why the author has defined the test function in this way. Why did he choose $\phi(8)=67/75$? Why the size is exactly 0.05?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a randomized test... it is not very common. Scrolling the various k's in your $Bin(10;0.5)$ you will never get exactly $\alpha=5\%$, thus you reject with probability 1 if $X>8$ and with probability $p$ if $X=8$

How to calculate $p$?

$$1\cdot\mathbb{P}[X=10]+1\cdot\mathbb{P}[X=9]+p\cdot\mathbb{P}[X=8]+0\cdot\mathbb{P}[X<8]=0.05$$
That is

$$0.0009765625+0.0097656250+p\cdot 0.0439453125=0.0500000000$$

$$p=0.8933333333=\frac{67}{75}$$

In a Real Statistics work, when you know that $X=8$ has a $p_{value}=5.47\%$ you have enough information to take your decision. Nobody is interested to get "exactly" $\alpha=5\%$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. One question, where this expression given 0.05 on the right side came from?

Comment: @user42912 : it's the fixed $\alpha=5\%$ stated in the exercise

Comment: Yes, I know but why did you multiply the probabilities by the values of the functions on the left side?

Comment: @user42912 : it's the equation to calculate $p$. I reject with probability 1 if $X>8$ and with probability $p$ (unknown ) if $X=8$. The total probability to reject is 0.05 fixed

Comment: yes, the only I didn't understand why you wrote: $0\cdot\mathbb{P}[X<8]$. Since we care only aboute the probability of rejection, all we have to do is the sum $0.0009765625+0.0097656250+p\cdot 0.0439453125=0.0500000000$ directly

Comment: @user42912 : don't worry about that! I added it only to complete exactly $\phi(x)$ your text defined. I can cancel it if confusing

Comment: Thank you very much again. One last question, why he uses only $\theta = 1/2$?

Comment: @user42912 : it's the null hypothesis. You do the same in any test

Comment: but the null hypothesis isn't $\theta\le 1/2$, instead of $\theta = 1/2$?

Comment: if we had an equality $\theta=1/2$,ok. But we have an inequality, shouldn't we test other values less than 1/2?

Comment: @user42912 you should know that $H_0=0.5$ and $H_0\leq 0.5$ are equivalent. It's a very basic fact due to the definition of $\alpha=\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0}[X\geq k]$

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's 100% clear!

Comment: I have another question (the last I promise), this $1\cdot\mathbb{P}[X=10]+1\cdot\mathbb{P}[X=9]+p\cdot\mathbb{P}[X=8]+0\cdot\mathbb{P}[X<8]=0.05$ you are using the law of total probability?

Comment: Since $\theta = 0.5$, the $H_0$ is true, then in order to know the probability of having the type I error ($\alpha$), it suffices to know the probability of rejection given $\theta = 0.5$, then $P(\text{reject } H_0)=P(\text{reject } H_0|X=8).P(X=8)+P(\text{reject } H_0|X=9).P(X=9)+P(\text{reject } H_0|X=10).P(X=10)$

Answer (score 1):

The rejection criterion is $\Pr_\theta[X \ge k_\alpha] \le \alpha$, and since under the null hypothesis, $X$ is binomial with $\theta = \frac{1}{2}$, this probability is given by the sum $$\Pr[X \ge k_\alpha \mid \theta = 1/2] = \sum_{x=k_\alpha}^n \binom{n}{x} \theta^x (1 - \theta)^{n-x} = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{x = k_\alpha}^n \binom{n}{x} = \frac{1}{2^{10}} \sum_{x = k_\alpha}^{10} \binom{10}{x} \le \alpha.$$  When we calculate this sum for various choices of $k_\alpha$, we get the table $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
k_\alpha & \Pr[X = k_\alpha \mid \theta = 1/2] & \Pr[X \ge k_\alpha \mid \theta = 1/2] \\
\hline
10 & \frac{1}{1024} & \frac{1}{1024} \approx 0.000976563 \\
9 & \frac{10}{1024} & \frac{11}{1024} \approx 0.0107422 \\
8 & \frac{45}{1024} & \frac{56}{1024} \approx 0.0546875 \\
7 & \frac{120}{1024} & \frac{176}{1024} \approx 0.171875 \\
\vdots & & \\
\end{array}$$
and the rightmost column are the values given in the problem.  The problem then is that the rejection criterion $X \ge 8$ cannot be used because the resulting Type I error is slightly too large (by about $0.0046875$) for a test of size $\alpha$; but the criterion $X \ge 9$, while resulting in a **level** $\alpha$ test, would have less power to reject the null than a test of **size** $\alpha$, because in some cases, when the truth is $\theta > 1/2$ and we should reject the null, we cannot because we might observe only $X = 8$ and the criterion requires $X \ge 9$.

So the remedy that is proposed is to employ a randomization step to determine when to reject the null when $X = 8$, in such a way that the size of the test is exactly equal to $\alpha$.  To do this, the example proposes to reject with some probability $p < 1$ when $X = 8$.  This is the "flip a coin" scenario they describe.  Now, it makes sense that, because the rejection region $X \ge 8$ is only *slightly* larger than $\alpha$, when we observe $X = 8$, we should be okay to reject the null *most* of the time, but not all of the time.  In other words, $p$ should be closer to $1$ than to $0$.  To determine exactly what value $p$ should be so that the Type I error is exactly $0.05$, we need to go back to the table and observe that the rightmost column is formed by cumulatively adding up the second column--i.e., this is a running total.  So the required value of $p$ is the one for which when we add $p$ times the probability of $X = 8$ to the running total, we get $0.05$; that is to say, $$\frac{1}{1024} + \frac{10}{1024} + \frac{45}{1024} p = 0.05 = \frac{1}{20}.$$  Solving this gives the claimed $$p = \frac{67}{75}.$$  So when we see $X = 8$, we flip that coin and reject the null with probability $67/75$, and the resulting Type I error is exactly $0.05$.

However, this sort of procedure, while theoretically sound, certainly should cause the statistician some degree of discomfort.  After all, the sample contained all the evidence that we had about $\theta$, and that sample does not change within a given experiment.  Yet, depending on the outcome of a *random* coin toss, one that has nothing to do with the underlying process that generated the sample itself, we make a decision about whether to reject the null.  This hardly seems "reasonable" from the perspective of making a statistical inference.  Another way to understand this is, if you conducted the experiment for $n = 10$ and found $X = 8$, and I conducted my own experiment with $n = 10$ and also found $X = 8$, you might, on the basis of the *same evidence*, conclude that $\theta > 1/2$ but I might not make that conclusion because my coin toss outcome was not the same as yours.  Yet the coin has nothing to do with the experiment that generated the outcome $X = 8$ in both cases.  This is why we do not see such randomized testing procedures commonly performed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. One question, how did you get this equation $\frac{1}{1024} + \frac{10}{1024} + \frac{45}{1024} p = 0.05 = \frac{1}{20}$? it seems you did $\phi(8)P(X=8)+\phi(9)P(X=9)+\phi(10)P(X=10)$

Answer (score 1):

considering the several question you are putting, I suppose that you are a little bit confused with this kind of problem. I try to explain you how to proceed in this case, trying to answer to all your questions.

First of all, considering the very well explanation of @heropup about uselessness of the randomized test, let's solve the following problem in a more commonly non - randomized test. If yuo want you can anyway randomize it...

**The problem:**
I played a "fair coin game" with a friend. I chose Head he Tail. We tossed "his fair coin" and bet $\$1,000$ ad any toss and these were the results

$$\{H-T-T-T-T-H-T-T-T-T\}$$

Result: in the time of a minute I loss 6 thousand dollars!!

**The doubt:**

Friend or not, I am wondering to understand if this was really a fair coin or it was biased in favour of Tail (he chose both Tail and the Coin)

**The solution:**

First of all I get a drawing of the binomial $Bin(10;0.5)$ that is the distribution of Tails under the Null hypothesis that my friend is not a robber...

[image]

As you can see, the probability of getting 8 or more tails in 10 tosses, is about $5.5\%$

This is the Type I error, the probability to reject $H_0$ in favour of a One tail hypothesis $H_1$ that the coin is biased in his favour.

You can randomize the test to get exactly 5% and not 5.47% as in the example but you do not get any plus-information. The test is "bordeline significative"  but it is not highly significative...if you state a Type I error of 1%, your pvalue of 5.47% is not enough to claim your money back...

Now suppose we fix an alternative hypotesis of $H_1: \theta=0.8$ and let's see what happens to our drawing

[image]

The yellow bars represent the probability to reject $H_0$ with the random sample above stated but under the alternative $H_1$: it's the Test Power:$68\%$.

**The conclusion**

The test is bordeline and not highly significative so I remain with my doubt because I'm not 99% sure of the robbery. Probably next time I will spend my $\$6,000$ for a Cruise to the Caribbean and not for gambling.

---

In a way I prefer to approach this problem (Bayesian approach), I assume a Uniform prior and evaluate

$$\frac{\int_0^{1/2}\theta^8(1-\theta)^2d\theta}{\int_{1/2}^1\theta^8(1-\theta)^2d\theta}=\frac{67}{1981}$$

Being the denominator greater than the numerator, my decision is in favour of the denominator, that is $\theta>\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your another answer. I didn't understand the second graph, what are the blue and red bars in the second graph?

Comment: @user42912 : oh yes understand! Blue and Yellow bars together is binomial 10 under $H_1$; Yellow bars only is $P(X>7|H_1)$: test power

Comment: ok, so looking to your graph what's the critical region?

Comment: In another words, 8 is in the critical region? Following heropup's answer, yes. However, $\phi(8)$ isn't zero or 1.